# Return list from while loop in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return-value

I'm trying to return a list `my_list` created within function `make_list` to use in the function `print_elems`.

I keep getting the error

> my_list is not defined

for when I ask to print it, after calling "make_list".

What am I doing incorrectly in trying to return "my_list"?

```
def make_list():
    my_list = []
    print("Enter \"-999\" to return list.")
    x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    while x != -999:
        my_list.append(x)
        x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    return my_list

def print_elems(user_list):
    print(user_list, sep=' ')


make_list()
print(my_list)
print_elems(my_list)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access the *local* variable `my_list`. You have to use the returned value instead by assigning it to a variable:

```
some_name = make_list()  # assign function result to variable
print(some_name)
print_elems(some_name)
```

On a side note, you probably want to slightly modify `print_elems`:

```
def print_elems(user_list):
    print(*user_list, sep=' ')
```

The `*` [unpacks](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) the list and passes its elements to the `print` function. Otherwise, when passing a single positional argument to `print`, the `sep` parameter will never be used.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info! I was just starting to look into that

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the return of your function to a variable:

```
tata = make_list()
print(tata)
```

The variable `my_list` is destroyed when you leave the scope of your function that defined it. That is why you return it.

---

See [Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules) and [PyTut: Scopes and namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)